create FlowDocument with picture in code behind
I want to create a FlowDocument with dynamic content (comes from a database) and add also a picture (e.g. company logo). Normal text is just fine, but the picture is not shown.
When I add an Image control to the MainWindow.xaml and assign the same bitmap to the .Source property, the image is showing in the Image control and in the FlowDocument. Even when I set .Source back to Nothing the picture stays visible in the FlowDocument. And the Visibility of the Image control can be Collapsed. That doesn't matter.
I can live with this work-around, but I wonder what happens to the bitmap when it is assigned to .Source of an Image control so it shows up in the FlowDocument too?
It would be nice to have a propper code without such tricks.
Complete sample project: https://fastupload.io/325a5463c3eaa5cc
created with: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-Bit) - Current Version 17.9.7
Private Function CreateFlowDocument() As FlowDocument
Dim myFlowDocument As New FlowDocument()
Dim myParagraph As New Paragraph(New Run("This is some text in the paragraph."))

Dim myFloater As New Floater()
myFloater.Width = 150 ' Set the width of the floater
myFloater.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right ' Set the alignment (e.g., left, center, right)

' Add content to the floater (e.g., an image or other UI elements)
Dim imageSource As New BitmapImage(New Uri("/pictures/sample_logo.jpg", UriKind.Relative))
Dim image As New Image() With {.Source = imageSource}
myFloater.Blocks.Add(New BlockUIContainer(image))
imgTest.Source = imageSource '<- the magic happens here, but why?
'imgTest.Source = Nothing

' Add the floater to the paragraph
myParagraph.Inlines.Add(myFloater)

myFlowDocument.Blocks.Add(myParagraph)

Return myFlowDocument

End Function
